# How can I separate a VMWare Server from the host's MAC Address on my router?

Tags: ip, router, virtual-machines, vmware-player, mac-address

I'm running a Debian LAMP Server in VMWare Player, using a bridged connection.

However, on my router the VM is showing up with the same MAC Address... therefore I can't set the VM to a static address.

I've tried changing the MAC in the .vmx, but to no success. I'm not really sure what to do or where to look now. I've tried Googling and I guess I don't know what I'm looking for or I just can't find it, hopefully someone here can help out.

Edit:

Definitely Bridged Connection

ARP Table From Ping:

```
  10.0.0.7              00-1a-73-82-da-c9     dynamic
  10.0.0.10             00-1a-73-82-da-c9     dynamic
```

7 is the Host OS
10 is the VM

Comment: What's the host OS?  Are you a superuser there?

Comment: Windows 7, yes I'm running as Admin the only account on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a problem with the system running off WiFi. When I used the Ethernet connection, the MAC Address returned to what it should have been.

Comment: It used to be that you couldn't change the MAC address of WiFi adapters.  I don't know that that's still the case, but it would explain what you're seeing here.

Answer (score 0):

What MAC address are you using?  If it's not a VMware MAC (00:50:56:...), you have to also include this config option:

```
ethernetN.addressType = “static”
```

Comment: It was something to do with it being on wireless. I switched they physical machine to an ethernet connection and the MACs show up fine.